# Domain expired on provider but SSL and Hosting are still good - how to get website up again?

Tags: ssl, domain, web-hosting, shared-hosting

So, apparently the domain was purchased at a different time. The hosting and files are still good, as is the SSL. Went ahead a purchased the domain name again. This is on Godaddy.

Do I need to connect the domain name and hosting together? If so how, it will not let me. I reissued a new SSL cert, but I still cannot access the website via the internet.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Godaddy technical support should be able to take care of this in a snap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to connect the domain name and hosting together?

Yes. Depending on how the hosting was configured, the hosting company will want one of the two:

- Simpler option: Move all DNS management to the hosting company. Go to your domain's control panel at GoDaddy, and change the [nameservers](https://uk.godaddy.com/help/set-custom-nameservers-for-domains-registered-with-godaddy-12317) to those provided by your hosting company.
- Manual management option: Keep DNS management at GoDaddy, but go to your domain's [DNS records](https://uk.godaddy.com/help/change-an-a-record-19239) control panel there and replace just the 'A' & 'AAAA' records with those provided by your hosting company. Make sure to change the records for both the bare domain *and* the "www" subdomain.

  (For email hosting, you'll also need to change 'MX' records, possibly add some 'TXT' ones.)

Note that the DNS records have a "TTL" – time for which visitors can cache the record before checking for changes. For example, if the old (wrong) record had a TTL of 1 hour, and you just changed it, you'll have to wait up to 1 hour for the DNS changes to be fully active. Changing the nameservers for the entire domain, in particular, can take up to a day or two.

> I reissued a new SSL cert, but I still cannot access the website via the internet.

Certificates do not tell visitors *where* to find your website; they're only used to confirm (certify) that the visitor has connected to the correct one. You need to have the domain working *before* the certificate will have any relevance.

Comment: OK, thanks. At the moment EVERYTHING is on Godaddy. The original domain name and ALL hosting files (woocommerce site) as hosted on Godaddy. The domain name expired prior to the hosting and SSL. I purchased the same domain name today but I still cannot figure out how to connect, the basically same domain name, to the already existing files - which are all hosted on Godaddy. So are you saying to change the A and AAA records to the domain name? Thanks.